# Scythe keyboard pedals

Tags: keyboard, udev

I have bought Scythe keyboard pedals:

```
kernel: usb 1-4.1.2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
kernel: usb 1-4.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0426, idProduct=3011
kernel: usb 1-4.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
amber2 kernel: usb 1-4.1.2: Manufacturer: MKEYBOARD
amber2 kernel: input: MKEYBOARD as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.2/usb1/1-4/1-4.1/1-4.1.2/1-4.1.2:1.0/0003:0426:3011.0007/input/input25
amber2 kernel: hid-generic 0003:0426:3011.0007: input,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [MKEYBOARD] on usb-0000:00:12.2-4.1.2/input0
amber2 kernel: usbhid 1-4.1.2:1.1: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
```

I have found [rgerganov/footswitch](https://github.com/rgerganov/footswitch) and I have installed which has installed one file to `/etc`: `udev/rules.d/19-footswitch.rules`

I did try to program the device with the `scythe -1 -a a` command. Executing `scythe -r` shows

```
[switch 1]: a
[switch 2]: undefined
[switch 3]: undefined
```

But it does not seem to do any input when I press the pedal.

I am concerned about the `couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint` message in the log.

Also, is the content of the `19-footswitch.rules` correct? Maybe it needs some tweaking?

```
ATTR{product}=="FootSwitch*"\
MODE:="0666"\
GROUP="hid"\
RUN+="keymap $name 0x70066 screenlock"\
SYMLINK+="footswitch"
```

If it is relevant, this is what I see for the device from `lshw -c input`:

```
  *-usb UNCLAIMED
       description: Keyboard
       vendor: MKEYBOARD
       physical id: 2
       bus info: usb@1:4.1.2
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: usb-1.10
       configuration: maxpower=256mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

Comment: Wilx, would you write that update as answer than accept it later. The question is well constructed and has enough details. Which may help other users. I don't want to flag it for closure then cleaned later.

Answer (score 0):

After reboot, it seems to work fine. I have mapped the pedals to CTRL, ALT, and SHIFT.